# XCode Boost Thread Example Compile Error

Tags: multithreading, boost, boost-thread, xcode4.4

Here's my basic boost code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::this_thread;
using namespace std;
// Global function called by thread
void GlobalFunction()
{
    for (int i=0;i<10;++i)
    {
        cout << i << "Do something in parallel with main method." << endl;
        boost::this_thread::yield();
    }
}
void GlobalThreadTest()
{
    boost::thread t(&GlobalFunction);
    for (int i = 0; i<10; ++i) {
        cout << i << "Do something in main method. " << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    GlobalThreadTest();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting lots of errors like this from xcode

> (null): "boost::this_thread::yield()", referenced from:
>   (null): "boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()",
>   referenced from: (null): "boost::system::system_category()",
>   referenced from: (null): "boost::system::generic_category()",
>   referenced from: (null): "boost::thread::start_thread()", referenced
>   from:

I have installed boost using macports and the header search paths in xcode is set to 
/opt/local/include/
This contains all the .hpp files.

2 Questions

1. Does boost create *.o files if so where are they stored?
2. How do I get xcode 4.2 to work with this boost thread example? If there is a flag I have to set, which parameter in xcode 4.2 do I set it in?

Thanks.

Comment: I think I need to build the boost thread library. I am able to run bootstrap.sh and get b2 but when I go to run b2 I see the following error. `/Users/Weels/user-config.jam:3: in modules.load
rule ing unknown in module user-config
/Users/Weels/Downloads/boost_1_50_0/tools/build/v2/build-system.jam:257: in load-config`